# Unsure why unreliable WiFi

Tags: networking, debian, unix, wifi

So I'm a little at my wits' end here. I have a device with WiFi capabilities connected to my WiFi router. It is quite literally 5 meters away from the router, and it works fine and fast when it's active, but somehow sometimes completely loses it.

From what I can tell, power management is off, so it doesn't look like it's falling asleep, but that is what it feels like.

I've ran a quick script on it an entire day to check for wlan0's IP periodically every minute to see if it loses connection to the router, but that didn't seem the case, it kept its IP constantly. It just seems to completely drop out after a while.

This is the configuration output:

```
wlan0     IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"Koets IoT"
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.472 GHz  Access Point: 18:A6:F7:5F:85:D9
          Bit Rate=43.3 Mb/s   Tx-Power=31 dBm
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=45/70  Signal level=-72 dBm
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0

lo        no wireless extensions.
```

It also seems to do well in terms of connectivity:

```
PING 192.168.1.101 (192.168.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=128 time=2.36 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=128 time=5.19 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=128 time=5.44 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=4 ttl=128 time=5.43 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=5 ttl=128 time=5.34 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=6 ttl=128 time=5.24 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=7 ttl=128 time=5.87 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=8 ttl=128 time=5.29 ms
```

Anything I can look or test for? I'd really like it to be stable. I have considered running scripts to restart its networking if it fails to respond, but that would be treating the symptoms and not the larger problem.

Comment: Is this a business network? It sounds like it's at your home.

Comment: 5 meters LOS should not be -72dB.  My office has an open ceiling in the warehouse and phone has -68dB at my desk to an AP in the rafters that I can barely see visually about 45m away.  The other half of the IT dept is in a elevated concrete bunker above the warehouse next to my 'fishbowl', I have a -54dB to their router, through obstruction.  What else is going on in the 2.4ghz range around you?  Can that laptop connect to other wifi networks or other APs on that same SSID?

Answer (score 1):

I'd guess there is either another device with the same SSID within the range (repeater?), which your device may reconnect to.

Or another option can be faulty firmware. Make sure you have the firmware updated on both sides - router + your device.

And try to inspect logs on your device for some hints related to the wlan0.

Comment: Same SSID?  Or merely operating on the same frequencies?

Comment: Coleague of mine said that he had at home wifi router, but he had problems connecting at the back of the house and the garden. So he bought wifi repeater. But then devices were locked to the repeater and didn't switch back to the router, despite that when he moved inside, the signal of the repeater was unusable and connection didn't work.